# What is the name of the font used in the Publix Super Markets, Inc. logo?

Tags: font-identification

Could you please tell me the name of the font used in the logo of Publix Super Markets, Inc.?

From https://sribu-sg.s3.amazonaws.com/assets/media/contest/2014/1/design-logo-untuk-pt-purwaland-development-housing-developer-52dd49b7a4b1b051af0001d6/ded95c4.jpg
[image: Mystery Font]

Neither [WhatTheFont!](http://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/) or [What Font Is](http://whatfontis.com/) return reliable results, with WhatTheFont! suggesting WorldOfWater and What Font Is suggesting HarryHeavy or Sinn, none of which are quite right.

Answer (score 1):

The characters in the Publix logo look very similar to a font family called 'Horatio' — with a small amount of modification to the dot over the 'i'. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Publix probably have a custom logo font from the scratch, so probability is there they might not have created all the alphabets (just created p-u-b-l-i-x).

Some fonts look similar but all the alphabets does not match exactly. You can check [Bauhaus](http://www.ffonts.net/Bauhaus.font?text=Publix) font and [Sinn](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/haiku/sinn/) only the shape of the x, the height of  i are different.

Comment: I have updated my comment I hope this should be good now.

Answer (score 0):

It's either custom drawn letters or modified from a stock font like Bauhaus. It's not likely out of the box.

Here are some similar free fonts that could be used as a starting point to modify: http://www.fontspace.com/category/bauhaus

Answer (score 0):

The font used is Blippo Bold, which doesn't have a digital equivalent, at least one that's decent. There's a freebie digitization called "Brandish" that's pretty bad.

Answer (score -1):

According to Delta Fonts, the font used for Publix logo is Opificio Bold.

http://deltafonts.com/publix-font/

Comment: Welcome to GD.SE! Your answer would be perfect, if you can add an screenshot to your answer.  Otherwise suppose the given link broken no one can proof your answer.

Answer (score -1):

My grandfather created that logo in the 70s, I doubt he used a certain typeface. I have never seen him use a computer either.

Comment: Sounds fascinating! As an answer it's a bit thin. Could become a good answer if you provided some more context. Told the whole story.